.NET 6 and Certificate Auth
My certificate auth set up for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API hosted in IIS is not working as expected.
The API is exposed from an Azure app gateway and I want to secure it with certificate auth.
Here is the code - Startup - ConfigureServices calls SetupAuthentication method as shown here:
public static void SetupAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    if (configuration == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    // Authentication
    services
        .AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CertificateAuthentication>(nameof(CertificateAuthentication), o => { });

    var authorizationConfig = configuration.GetSection(nameof(AuthorizationConfig)).Get<AuthorizationConfig>();
    services.AddAuthorization(options
                => options.AddPolicy(nameof(ConfiguredAuthorization), policy
                    => policy.Requirements.Add(new ConfiguredAuthorization(authorizationConfig))));
}

appsettings.json has thumbprints:
"CertificateConfig": {
        "AllowedThumbprints": {
            "cert1": "thumbprint1",
            "cert2": "thumbprint2",
            "cert3": "thumbprint3"
        }
    },

CertificateAuthentication.cs:
namespace My.Web.API.Auth
{
    public class CertificateAuthentication : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly CertificateConfig _certificateConfig;
        private readonly ILogger<CertificateAuthentication> _logger;
        
        public CertificateAuthentication(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock,
            ILogger<CertificateAuthentication> authLogger,
            IOptions<CertificateConfig> certificateConfig)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            // Can be ignored
        }
        
        protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var certificate = Request.HttpContext?.Connection?.ClientCertificate;

            if (certificate == null)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("No client certificate was provided");
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing certificate"));
            }

            var allowedThumbprint = _certificateConfig.AllowedThumbprints
                                                      .FirstOrDefault(t => certificate.Thumbprint.Equals(t.Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (allowedThumbprint.Equals(default(KeyValuePair<string, string>)))
            {
                _logger.LogWarning($"The provided client certificate was not in the allowed list");
                return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Certificate not allowed"));
            }

            var claims = new[] { new Claim("Certificate", allowedThumbprint.Key) };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), Scheme.Name);

            return Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket));
        }
    }
}

web.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location path="." xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
        
        <system.webServer>
            <security xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert" />
            </security>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="EnvName" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" />
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>

Controller is decorated with
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = nameof(CertificateAuthentication))]

In IIS, the authentication is set to "Anonymous Enabled" true, other settings are set to false. SSL Settings, Require SSL is checked and Accept are selected.

There are different types of Certificates.  The SSL/TLS is used to establish a encrypted connection between client and server and is not the certificate that is used for authentication.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@marc_s thank you for the edits. I will ensure I format it in the future per your changes.

@jdweng My set up looks pretty similar, can you please tell me what is incorrect in the way I am trying to do it? I am not at all experienced with authentication stuff may be I am missing out important details. In other words, can you please dumb it down for me?

It is not just the code.  The link says : You must configure your server for certificate authentication, be it IIS, Kestrel, Azure Web Apps, or whatever else you're using.

Please ensure that your IIS site is properly configured with an HTTPS binding using a valid SSL certificate. The client certificate authentication requires the server to be accessible over HTTPS, and the certificate should be correctly bound to the site.

In the last line in my question I have mentioned my IIS set up details. And to add yes I have https binding with a certificate and the site is accessible if I set ignore on SSL settings in IIS.

I followed this https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/certificate-based-authentication-in-asp-net-core-web-api-aad37a33d448 but I am now getting Error: BAD_PKCS12_DATA. In the settings I uploaded the cert pfx and gave the host name.

You can check the Application log or System log in the Windows Event Log may provide more error details and help further diagnose the problem.
